# Missing annotations when implementing JAX-WS SEI in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have been using Eclipse Indigo to create a web service using JAX-WS and, when implementing operations from the SEI, methods were inheriting the corresponding annotations (such as @WebMethod) also in the SIB.

Today I switched to Eclipse Luna and I noticed that annotations aren't inherited anymore, so I need to add them manually by copying them from the SEI to the SIB. Is there a way to obtain the same behaviour as the one in the previous version?